# Extract information from HTML document with C

Tags: c, html-parsing

In my quest to learn C (Plain C, not C#, nor C++. I have my reasons.), I have come across the need to extract some information from a HTML document, fetched from a URL. Namely, I want all href attributes from the links residing in a certain unordered list on the page, in an array of strings. These URLs point at images I want to download and store in a zip file.

Now, I've asked a few people I know are good at C, and they have either told me off with "C is the wrong tool", or pointed me at libXML, which is apparently famous for it's scarce documentation. I've also looked at libsoup and libtidy, but I can't seem to stitch the pieces together.

What approach/library should I pick? Does anyone know of some example code I could look at?

EDIT: Seeing that half the comments are telling me to use something other than C, I'll add that I'm not looking for the "right tool for the job". I'd probably use Ruby if I just wanted to get it done ASAP, simply because I'm comfortable with it. It's part of my quest to learn C, and as such, I'm looking for a pure C solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say that C is not the appropriate tool. If the computer can do it, you can write it in C. However, you will get the work done much faster with a more appropriate language. I vote for Perl.

Comment: Well, for parsing, I would recommend the classic lex/yacc (or flex/bison) combo. There are html grammars floating somewhere, google should find some.

Comment: What you are asking OR want to do is known as `CRAWLER`. best programming language to achieve this is `Perl`.

Comment: @pmg -- The massaging part is what's giving me trouble :)

Comment: Please see my edit note.

Comment: For a robust solution you need an HTML parser, period. You may however want to write your own "light-parser" for learning purposes. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a quest to learn C, then I would use the standard library  and .

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/

The easiest is to use something else to get the page, write it to a local file, then pass the file name into your program.  Print your output to STDOUT.